# RTSP streaming in HTML5

Tags: html, video-streaming, live-streaming

I want to stream through IP camera in HTML5,
I used following code

`<video><source src="rtsp://camera-ip/video.sav">`

It is not streaming as all of us know that html5 doesn't support `rtsp://` protocol yet.

So I gathered some information, and I came 2 know that it can be done by using frame by frame. Can anybody guide me how to achieve this by using frame by frame??

Comment: I think you are referring possibly to mjpeg, which would send a frame at a time to an html based player, but your camera would have to support the mjpeg format not rtsp.

Comment: @MichelleCannon: Is there any way to convert in into mpeg??

Comment: convert what to mpeg, the rtsp stream , no, rtsp is a transport protocol mpeg is a video format. are you asking if you can do something on the server to convert your streams from the camera to mjpeg, the answer largely depends on what servers you use and what kind of post-processing on the server you are willing to do.

Comment: @MichelleCannon: Ohh so I either need wowza or ffmpeg server to do so..